# Sorting columns then using cell() function

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a datatable with a sortable column. Clicking the header sorts it. So far so good.
However, after sorting, I then want to iterate the cells in the column. So I do this:

```
datatable.column(".latest").nodes().each(function (node, index, dt) {
var the_cell = this.cell(index, '.sto_bid').node();
```

However, this pulls back the cell before the column was sorted. In other words, index=0 is pulling back what is now the last cell in the column. How do you reset the indexes when you sort, so cell(0, '.sto_bid') will return the first cell shown in the table?

The docs seem to suggest that calling draw() does what I need - it resets the data. It doesn't do anything for me when I do this first:

```
datatable.draw()
```

The ordering index is still backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

```
// My custom sort function on the raw data array
sortFilteredGridData();

// Remove all rows from the table
table.clear();

// Add the data back to the table
table.rows.add(filteredGridData);

// I have a fixed header
table.fixedHeader.adjust();

// Re-draw
table.draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to apply the searched tag to your returned data:

```
contentTable.cells({search:'applied'}, ".latest").nodes();
```

This should get all of the DOM elements of the cells in the .latest column, in the order they exist on the page. It kind of takes a different approach to grabbing the nodes than your code does so I don't know how to exactly apply it to your situation, but this should get you in the right direction